# UUID('...') is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, uuid

I get this error when i try to pass the UUID attribute to url parameter.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^historia-clinica/(?P<uuid>[W\d\-]+)/$', ClinicHistoryDetail.as_view(), name='...'),
]
```

views.py

```
class ClinicHistoryDetail(...):
     ...
     my_object = MyModel.objects.create(...)
     ...
     return redirect(reverse('namespace:name', kwargs={'uuid' : my_object.id}))
```

model.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It'd be better if you could show us how you passed it and also what `ClinicHistoryDetail` is doing.

Answer (score 92):

There is a bug ticket on Django regarding this issue however a custom so called 'complex encoder' by python docs can help you.

```
import json
from uuid import UUID


class UUIDEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, UUID):
            # if the obj is uuid, we simply return the value of uuid
            return obj.hex
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Now if we did something like this

```
json.dumps(my_object, cls=UUIDEncoder)
```

Your uuid field should be encoded.

Comment: `json.dumps(my_object.__dict__, cls=UUIDEncoder)` is working

Comment: isn't there a way to get a string uuid, call toString on it or whatever?

Comment: This strips hyphens and changes the value. Downvote!

Comment: @mmla try `u = UUID(obj.hex)` and you will see that it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's possible to use `str(obj)` in place of `obj.hex` if you want to keep the hyphens.

Answer (score 41):

Convert UUID to str.

`uuid_str = str(uuid_item)`

Comment: But why doesn't the json encoder just do this?

Comment: The problem is Rikki UUID is a binary format that doesnt have a canonical string representation, at least as far as the computer is aware, due to the complexities added by code pages and unicode vs ascii etc (And this is partly a fault of the JSON spec not being clear on this). The JSON decoder tries not to make assumptions because those might be wrong. Its probably not the most practical approach but its the comp-sci *correct* approach, particularly with pythons mantra of explicit-not-implicit.

Answer (score 14):

Looks like this error is no more relevant for django, while using `DjangoJSONEncoder`. No need to write own custom encoder. Provided by django handles most known serializing problems.

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
 
json.dumps(my_object, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder)

Answer (score 8):

An alternative is to use `default=str`. I leave it for reference:

```py
import uuid
import json

pk = uuid.UUID("04d8d2dc-e81b-4eaa-8883-d1e361a08da8")
o = json.dumps({"pk": pk}, default=str)
print(o)
```

Outputs:

```
{"pk": "04d8d2dc-e81b-4eaa-8883-d1e361a08da8"}
```

Answer (score 6):

I use convert function for this, it is simple and clean.

```
import json
from uuid import UUID
def uuid_convert(o):
        if isinstance(o, UUID):
            return o.hex

json.dumps(users,indent=4,default=uuid_convert)
```

Answer (score 5):

For using the UUID in a URL like that, you should pass it as a string:

```
 return redirect(reverse('namespace:name', kwargs={'uuid' : str(object.id)}))
```

FYI - it looks like WIMs answer is a bit more thorough. Your regex should certainly be tightened up. If you end up using the string representation of the slug, you'll want a regex like this: `[A-Za-z0-9\-]+` which allows for alphanumerics and hyphens.

Comment: You are probably still getting your error because neither the UUID or the hex is a serializable object. You should make them a string in your kwargs dictionary
`str(object.id)` or `str(object.id.hex)`
Then just make sure that your regex matches the option that you choose. If it's hex, use `[0-9a-f]{32}`. Otherwise, use `[A-Za-z0-9\-]+`

Answer (score 2):

I used a lambda function to inline str() the object.

```
import uuid
import json

mydict = {
    "key1":"value1",
    "guid1": uuid.uuid4()
}

myjson = json.dumps(mydict, default=lambda x : str(x))

print(myjson)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with a UUID field in a database model that I wanted to print out for debugging. I found that the `pprint()` function from the `pprint` module can handle this. You can also give it an `indent` argument to get the same kind of indented output that you would get from `json.dumps()`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint

Example:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> import pprint
>>> import json
>>> x = uuid.UUID('12345678123456781234567812345678')
>>> x
UUID('12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678')
>>> print(x)
12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678
>>> json.dumps(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
...
...
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: UUID('12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678') is not JSON serializable
>>> pprint.pprint(x)
UUID('12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678')
```