# Django Rest Framework: Just get certain values of a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield, django-related-manager

I'm using Django Rest Framework to write my API. I want to write different values than the the id (specifically the uuid) into my serializer.

Let me give you the basic setup first. I have a model called `House` which has amongst other values a pk and a uuid. And I have a second model called `Citizen` which also has a pk and a uuid. `House` and `Citizen` have a ManyToMany relationship with each other.

I would like to have a serializer that just gives back an array of it's citizen.

Here is the not working pseudo code that I tried (and failed):

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()
    citizen = serializers.UUIDField(source="citizen.uuid")

    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = [
            "uuid",
            "address",
            "citizen",
            ...
        ]
```

This serializer throws the error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `citizen` on serializer `HouseListSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `House` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'uuid'.
```

But on my model for the `House` I have explicitly `citizen = models.ManyToManyField(Citizen)`.

If I just don't specify any serializer and just leave citizen in the fields array, I just get an array of the PKs which I can't use.

How can I get an array of the UUIDs here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need a serializer class for your Citizen model.

```
class CitizenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    uuid = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Citizen
        fields = ('uuid', )
```

We will then add the `CitizenSerializer` to your `HouseSerializer`. Note that we need the `many=True` argument for `ManyToManyField` relation.

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()
    citizen = CitizenSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        ...
```

You can read more about this [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects)

Comment: Kinda obious, I'm sometimes stuck in my head. Thank you for your help, this solution is simple and works!

Answer (score 2):

You can use SlugRelatedField like this:

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()
    citizen = serializers.SlugRelatedField( many=True,
    read_only=True,
    slug_field='uuid')
```

read the [drf doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This seems to work, only thing is I get the error: `TypeError: Object of type 'UUID' is not JSON serializable` :(

Comment: It seems like this is a deeper issue with Django... which is very unfortunate, otherwise your solution would've been a damned clear oneliner! See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588126/uuid-is-not-json-serializable