# MongoDB / PyMongo / Python (Time): Getting the Datetime as String

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB database with the following structure within my documents:

```
> "_id": {
>       "mandant": "a4da7117-2763-48df-b3a3-d50a0f6006fe",
>       "ersteller": "9bc79ce4-c23a-4c24-a857-80f94a341d39",
>       "sender": "9bc79ce4-c23a-4c24-a857-80f94a341d39",
>       "vorgang": "c08382ed-143f-46f7-8382-ed143f26f7b8",
>       "nachricht": "6c9d3386-001f-4809-9d33-86001fd80990"
>     },
>     "_class": "de.codecraft.amt.storage.model.XAmtshilfe",
>     "created": {
>       "$date": "2018-10-02T09:20:05.060Z"
>     },
```

When I query with:

```
collection = db.find({}, {"_id": 0, "created": 1})
```

I got the following result:

```
{'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 13, 40, 4, 879000)}
```

**How can I reach the pure datetime value, so I am able to parse it into other forms of time- types?**

**Thank you!**

Comment: well... but `datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 13, 40, 4, 879000)` is a *pure datetime value* (in your words)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyMongo casts timestamps into the native [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) structure. You can then use the `.isoformat()` or `.strftime(<format>)` methods to convert it to a string.

So, continuing on your example

```
objects = db.find({}, {"_id": 0, "created": 1})
for obj in objects:
    dt = obj['created']
    time_str = dt.isoformat()
    # ...
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, thank you so much, works perfect. I definitely will remember that! :)

Answer (score 3):

If someone wants to convert not only single `datetime` value but all values in a document, below json encoder could be helpful.

```py
import json
import datetime

class MongoDbEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.astimezone().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

# usage
json_document = json.dumps(result, cls=MongoDbEncoder)
```

I've got a hint from [UUID conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159596/361100).

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert to string during the query:

```
pipe =
[  
   {  
      "$project":{  
         "_id":0,
         "created":{ "$dateToString":{"format":"%Y%m%dT%H%M", "date":"$created"}},
      }
   }
]
objects = db.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
```