# how to convert string to dictionary with a datetime.datetime object in it

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a string, which I retrieved as a nested JSON field from a Mongo database

```
"[{'actionId': '29df54c0-9f08-4231-8eb2-ca2457003f2d', 'actionName': 'Create a team', 'userActionStatus': 'COMPLETED', 'currentCount': 1, 'targetCount': 1, 'lastActionDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 24, 14, 17, 17, 785000)}]"
```

I'm unable to parse the json with json.loads, as it's throwing a `Expected value at column...` error. Which is caused by the datetime.datatime object

Any ideas on how to parse this?

Comment: It's  not valid JSON because it contains a *datetime.datetime* object, which is not a valid JSON data type, so you have convert that first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596070/mongodb-pymongo-python-time-getting-the-datetime-as-string

Comment: That's not valid JSON - not just because of the `datetime.datetime` object (which is neither a string nor a numeric/Boolean/null value), but also because you have to enclose string in double quites like `"..."`, not single quotes `'...'` as you have. Anyway, you can parse this with [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), but it's [**not** considered safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451/6146136)

Comment: Have a look at: [Way to use ast.literal_eval() to convert string into a datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235606/way-to-use-ast-literal-eval-to-convert-string-into-a-datetime/4235622#4235622)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you trust the string returned by Mongo, you can use `eval`:

```
import datetime

s = "[{'actionId': '29df54c0-9f08-4231-8eb2-ca2457003f2d', 'actionName': 'Create a team', 'userActionStatus': 'COMPLETED', 'currentCount': 1, 'targetCount': 1, 'lastActionDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 24, 14, 17, 17, 785000)}]"

out = eval(s)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
[{'actionId': '29df54c0-9f08-4231-8eb2-ca2457003f2d',
  'actionName': 'Create a team',
  'userActionStatus': 'COMPLETED',
  'currentCount': 1,
  'targetCount': 1,
  'lastActionDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 24, 14, 17, 17, 785000)}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"[{'actionId': '29df54c0-9f08-4231-8eb2-ca2457003f2d', 'actionName': 'Create a team', 'userActionStatus': 'COMPLETED', 'currentCount': 1, 'targetCount': 1, 'lastActionDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 24, 14, 17, 17, 785000)}]"
```

This is not legal JSON, observe that single quotes are used, whilst [RFC7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159.html) stipulates double quotes (`"`), also `datetime.datetime` is not valid literal under rules shown in linked document.

You apparently got representation of `python` structure or in other words saved result of `print`ing structure rather than structure itself. Adjust your code so you are able to access structure.