# Minimal Python object that can't be uJson'd

Tags: python, json, ujson

Ujson (and probably other json libraries) for python will reject some objects. A good example is Ulid; you can't put a Ulid into a dict and then expect uJson to correctly dump it. However if I make an empty class, uJson will happily encode it. I'd like to write a unit test that shows that we correctly handle objects that will cause ujson to choke, but I'd rather not import a library just for that purpose. What's a minimal python object that can't be ujson'd?

Comment: Hm. `ujson` seems to try very hard to produce *something* for many values, whether or not that makes sense. `...` and `NotImplemented` both are serialized as the empty object `{}`; a socket produces an object that describes it somewhat, `ujson.dumps(socket.socket()) ==
'{"family":2,"proto":0,"timeout":null,"type":1}'`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure there *is* such a value; if all else fails, it seems an empty `{}` is returned.

Comment: As this question points out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588126/uuid-is-not-json-serializable there are some classes that cannot be serialized.

Comment: That question doesn't mention `ujson` at all. Ideally, JSON encoding should not be lossy, or at least minimally lossy: for instance, usually you don't care *too* much if both tuples and lists are encoded as JSON arrays. But `ujson` seems to be very liberal in how it encodes seeming unencodable values: it just gives you an empty object, and in many cases the object you get back can't be decoded into anything like the Python value that produced it.

Comment: Consider the output of `ujson.dumps(int)`, the encoding of the type `int`, not an instance of `int`: `'{"denominator":{},"imag":{},"numerator":{},"real":{}}'`. There's no particular reason why a type should be JSON-encodable, but there it is.

Comment: I update the question's title to be ujson specific, though other json libraries appear to have similar issues. I'm not trying to fix the problem, I'm trying to make write a test that exercises the problem without having to import Ulid or the like.

Comment: My point is, `uJSON` appears to go out of its way to *avoid* being unable to encode an object. Can you post an example of `ujson.dumps` failing to encode an object, even if you do import your ulid module?

Comment: Using ulid-py 0.0.12: 
```ujson.dumps(ulid.new())``` will raise `OverflowError: Unterminated UTF-8 sequence when encoding string`